# Jasmine-Jquery not loading JSON file

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am learning writing unit test using [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/index.html)-[Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/) for my application build on [AngularJs](https://angularjs.org/). I want to load test data from a json file. I am using [Jasmine-Jquery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery) to read json fixtures. In my karma config file I have following:

```
// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
            //dependencies...
            '../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            '../bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            '../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            '../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',

            // main module app.js.
            '../public/app.js',


            //all the controllers
            '../public/app/controllers/CalculatorCtrl.js',
            '../public/app/controllers/ScenaryCtrl.js',

            //test dependencies...
            '../bower_components/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js',

            //pattern to include all the test files...
            '../public/app/**/*Spec.js',

          // JSON fixture
          { 
            pattern:  '../public/app/**/*.json',
            watched:  true,
            served:   true,
            included: false }
            ],
```

In my spec file I am doing this:

```
beforeEach(function(){
   jasmine.getJSONFixtures().fixturesPath = 'public/app/controllers/test/fixtures/';
    var data=getJSONFixture('myjsonfixtures.json');
    console.log(data);
});
```

When I run test cases I get following error in console:

```
18 09 2015 18:02:03.841:INFO [Chrome 45.0.2454 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket 1bzPssO0gtZ_lqHlAAAA with id 52911560
Chrome 45.0.2454 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 2 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
18 09 2015 18:02:04.288:WARN [web-server]: 404: /public/app/controllers/test/fixtures/myjsonfixtures.json?_=1442579524156
Chrome 45.0.2454 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught Error: JSONFixture could not be loaded: public/app/controllers/test/fixtures/myjsonfixtures.json (status: error, message: undefined)
  at G:/My%20Temp%20Angular/Calculator/Karma%20with%20Jasmine/bower_components/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js:260
Chrome 45.0.2454 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 2 ERROR (0.089 secs / 0 secs)
```

I don't know why the data is not getting loaded. I am not able to catch what I am missing.

Comment: did you find a solution.. it would be great if you could share

Comment: No I have not found it yet.